# How would one simulate proxy functions without the HttpListener or TCPListener components in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

How can I simulate the functions/actions of a proxy server but without calling elements like HttpListener or TcpListener?  How can I generate them from within my C# application?

I've been able to get as far as getting actual data streamed back to my WebBrowser element in my C# application but upon viewing the results, it gives me errors.  The reason being is because I'm viewing the LITERAL string and there are JS/CSS components within the resulting HTML stream that makes references to objects via relative URIs.  Obviously, my solution thinks they're local and, as such, can't resolve them.

I'm missing proxy-like functions where it should just hand off the stream back to my mock browser and display properly.  However, looking at sample proxy server codes built on C#, they're all built as servers using listeners.  I'd like it to be something that I can instantiate locally without the need to create a listening interface.

Now, you may be wondering why I'm trying to do this?  Well, there are a couple of reasons:

- To be able to inject headers ad-hoc so I can test internal web servers
- To run as a headless (no GUI) component that can take either HTTP or HTTPS streams from other .NET components and inject headers from, yet, other .NET components.
- Some other back-end stuff that I think might but won't know until I have this in place.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var baseUrl = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
            client.Headers.Add("Token1", textBox2.Text);
            client.Headers.Add("Token2",textBox3.Text);

            byte[] requestHTML = client.DownloadData(textBox1.Text);
            string sourceHTML = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(requestHTML);

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sourceHTML);

            //"//*[@background or @lowsrc or @src or @href]"    
            foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@href]"))
            {
                //Console.Out.WriteLine(link.ToString());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Attributes["href"].Value))
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Before: " + att.Value);
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine(att.Value.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseUrl, att.Value));
                    link.Attributes["href"].Value = new Uri(baseUrl, att.Value).ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("After: " + link.Attributes["href"].Value);

                    //att.Value = this.AbsoluteUrlByRelative(att.Value);
                }
            }

            foreach (HtmlNode link2 in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@src]"))
            {
                //Console.Out.WriteLine(link.ToString());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link2.Attributes["src"].Value))
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = link2.Attributes["src"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Before: " + att.Value);
                //    //Console.Out.WriteLine(att.Value.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseUrl, att.Value));
                    if (!att.Value.Contains("/WS"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("HIT ME!");
                        var output = "/WS/" + att.Value;
                        link2.Attributes["src"].Value = new Uri(baseUrl, output).ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("After HIT: " + link2.Attributes["src"].Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        link2.Attributes["src"].Value = new Uri(baseUrl, att.Value).ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("After: " + link2.Attributes["src"].Value);
                    }


                //    //att.Value = this.AbsoluteUrlByRelative(att.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
            Console.WriteLine("+========================+");
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

        }
    }
}
```

Again, this is just prototyped code so forgive the wacky spacing and commenting.  In the end, it will be more formal.  Right now, this monkey is killing my back.

Comment: I've been working with this code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging and it works great as a standalone.  I'm wondering if instead of using an IP address and port, can we have the input be another stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using something like `NMock` or similar? It would mean having to introduce interfaces so that the mocks can be injected, but still beats doing it almost any other way, IMHO...

From the NMock site:

> NMock is a dynamic mock object library for .NET. Mock objects make it
>   easier to test single components—often single classes—without relying
>   on real implementations of all of the other components. This means we
>   can test just one class, rather than a whole tree of objects, and can
>   pinpoint bugs much more clearly. Mock objects are often used during
>   Test Driven Development.

You would mock the proxy server more or less like this:

```
var mocks = new Mockery();
var mockProxyServer = mocks.NewMock<IMyProxyServer>();
```

That's all you need to do. As you can see, it's interface-dependent. But usually all that I've needed to do is Refactor->Extract Interfaces from the relevant class in VS.

Setting up the simulation is usually done within the context of the unit test, like:

```
public class TransferFundsPresenterTest
{
    private Mockery mocks;
    private IMyProxyServer mockProxyServer

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mocks = new Mockery();
        mockProxyServer = mocks.NewMock<IMyProxyServer>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestProxyFunction()
    {
        Expect.Once.On(mockProxyServer).
            Method("ProxyFunctionA").
            With("1234").   //  <-- simulate the input params here
            Will(Return.Value("Test"));  // <-- simulate the output from server here
    }
```

This is just a basic example. You can do a lot more, it's a very flexible library.

You really should take a look at the `NMock` site, it's pretty easy to get fully up to speed with the library.

http://www.nmock.org/index.html

Comment: How would this work?  Do I have to create an interface that simulates my inbound traffic?  Maybe you can shed some light (pseudocode) to help me understand?

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer.  Not sure how I will make it work but I appreciate the effort, nonetheless.